# Objective C to Swift translate

Tags: ios

I am having difficulties translating an Objective C "method" to swift.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

**Objective C**

```
NSDictionary *fields = @{@"msg": @"connect", @"version": version, @"support": support};
```

**My attempt in Swift (wrong)**

```
let fields:Dictionary = {"msg": "connect", "version": version, "support": support}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift uses square brackets for Array and Dictionary:

```
let fields: Dictionary = ["msg": "connect", "version": version, "support": support]
```

it's just the format of the content between the brackets which determines what it is